How to make sure to unmount component when URL param changes (but using same component) in NextJs with React-query?
I will make my example as simple as possible. I have userProfile component
// UserProfie.tsx

const UserProfile = ({id}) => {
  const {data: userData} = useUser(id);

  console.log(userData.id); // this will be printed whenever component runs

  return <>
    {/* UserDetail has a couple of hooks which use fetch */}
    <UserDetail userId={userData.id} />
  </>

}


// userUser.tsx

export const useUser = (userId) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['user'],
    queryFn: async () => {
      await getUser(userId);  // fetch
    },
    gcTime: 0,  // clear cache when page changes
    staleTime: 0,
  })
}

This displays user data properly at the first time. But here is the problem.

When I use <Link /> to go to another user's profile (ex: /user/1 to /user/2).
It changes the URL and user data (id: 2) is displayed properly.
The console.log prints undefined.
Click "back button" from Chrome browser
The URL changes from /user/2 to /user/1.
But still user 2 data is displayed instead of user 1
The console.log prints 2 -> useUser(2) executed.
Then another console.log prints 1. But useUser(1) is not executed (I don't know why)
If I remove gcTime, then even step 2 doesn't display user 2 data.
My theory is using <Link /> unmounts component -> react-query garbage-collection.
But "back button" doesn't unmount component -> no garbage-collection -> that's why in step 7, userData is still 2 rather than undefined -> useUser(2) called in user 1 page.

How can I make sure to reload (or refetch) data whenever URL changes even if using the same component?
(I am using NextJs 14 and react-query 5)

queryKey: ['user']

Your query depends on userId, so it should be in the query key
export const useUser = (userId) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['user', userId],
    queryFn: () => getUser(userId),
    staleTime: 0,
  })
}


The query key is the least one I took care of when I was reading the official document! Thanks a lot!
